# Flutter: internet connection checker using with provider through out the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I am facing an error when i try to use internet connection checker with provider stream provider i used this tutorialhttps://medium.com/flutter-community/network-aware-flutter-application-using-provider-and-data-connection-checker-f6092134a98 with data checker plugin
[the image of main. Dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbjhL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do just as the error shows you.

```dart
StreamProvider<InternetConnectionStatus>(
  initialData: //This one is the one you're missing
  create:
  child:
)
```

> `initialData` determines the value exposed until the Stream emits a value.

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html

Maybe make a screenshot next time ;)